# display something from a bash script run at linux startup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, cron

I work on an installation script for an embedded system (over ssh).

To do that, I have a first bash script who manage the partition size. After that, this script configure the execution of a second bash scrit at reboot with crontab.

The second bash script download and compile many things and it could take few hours. During this, the system must not be stopped!
The user could unplug the power of the system, and the best way to prevent any trouble with this is to show the installation progression to the user.
The user have to reconnect itself manually after the first reboot.

How can I print something into the ssh session of the user with the script launch by crontab at reboot?

Answer (score 1):

you can put your message into any of the startup script. For example putting this line
**echo "message you want to print at startup"**
into **~/.bashrc** file will print **"message you want to print at startup"** at startup after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can modifiy SSHD to display a banner by modifying the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and uncommenting the `Banner` parameter.  You can have your cron job or whatever you want update the file that it uses for the banner.  The downside to this is that this message is only updated when the `sshd` is started.